# Permission File/Folder delete only file inside

Tags: permissions

I'm the owner, because I can not delete the folders,
but can I delete the files inside them?

```
     4 drwxr-xr-x 16 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 15:14 .
     4 drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1  4096 2018-01-09 11:56 ..
     4 drwxr-xr-x  3 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 12:25 IL_180
     4 drwxr-xr-x  3 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 12:25 IL_190
     4 drwxr-xr-x 11 user1 user1  4096 2017-12-27 10:27 IL_191
     4 drwxr-xr-x 15 user1 user1  4096 2018-01-19 16:08 IL_192
     4 drwxr-xr-x  7 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 14:20 IL_193
     4 drwxr-xr-x  5 user1 user1  4096 2018-01-18 16:22 IL_194
     4 drwxr-xr-x  8 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-02 10:27 IL_196
     4 drwxr-xr-x 18 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-08 16:06 IL_197
     4 drwxr-xr-x 12 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 12:49 IL_198
     4 drwxr-xr-x 10 user1 user1  4096 2018-02-20 14:19 IL_199
```

> **update**

sorry, the problem is in share samba with windows OS

Comment: Do you mean you are NOT the owner ?

Comment: To remove a file (whether a plain file or a directory) you need write permission on its parent directory

Comment: @hatterman sorry, i have update the question

Comment: @steeldriver sorry, i have update the question

Comment: If you do not own the directory all you can do is save the file with no content. But the file name you can  not remove without write permission on the directory the file is in